# Thumbnail grid issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, multiple-instances

I was hoping someone could take a look at the thumbnail grids on this page and help me understand why the first functions but the second does not.

http://bitfidelity.com/temp/index.html

Both are supposed to expand when clicked, but the images in the second just act as regular image links. I assume I have to uniquely identify each thumbnail grid so the script activates more than once, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

The grid is taken from a codrops article at http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the same IDs for both `<ul>` elements - that is why only the first list works, as jQuery will only select the first occurrence. You will have to use a different ID (not too practical), or simply use a class instead (that is applied to all `<ul>` elements that you want the effect to work on).

The selector is in your `grid.js` file, line 167:

```
var $grid = $('#og-grid'),
```

Try using a different selector, like:

```
var $grid = $('.og-grid'),
```

Comment: Thank you, Terry. I changed the selector in grid.js and the second grid now expands when clicked, but some of its functionality appears to be broken. The arrows stick in place after expansion and the positions of the thumbnails pushed downward do not revert to the normal grid. I'd like to try using different IDs, but I'm pretty new to javascript and am not sure how to integrate the new IDs into grid.js.

Answer (score 0):

BitFidelity, I was having the same issue and tackled it simply by inserting a `<li class="divider">` into the thumbnail and then styling that class (ie, `display:block; margin-top:200px;`

Essentially, rather than creating two instances of the grid, you're just inserting dividers into a single instance. I used H3s to title each section of the grid. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new function in `grid.js` which will find class `"og-expanded"` 
and remove its inline css and call this function in `showPreview()` function and `initItemsEvents()` function.

```
function removeinlinecss(){ $ ('ul li').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('og-expanded')){ $(this).removeAttr("style");}});
}
```